# Calculate percentage by categories from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, summary

Assume that, following a survey, I have an information table set as a pandas dataframe, containing `sex`,`age` and `answer` (to a given question). I give hereafter a small example:

```
    sex     age     answer
0   M   <25         yes
1   M   <25         no
2   M   [25-65]     no
3   M   [25-65]     yes
4   M   [25-65]     yes
5   M   >65         no
6   M   >65         yes
7   F   <25         yes
8   F   <25         yes
9   F   [25-65]     yes
10  F   [25-65]     no
11  F   [25-65]     no
12  F   >65         yes
13  F   >65         no
```

From this table, one can determine what is the percentage of `yes` by `age` and `sex`; calculated *by hand*, one will easily obtain the following summary table:

```
    %yes        M       F
0   <25         50.00   100.00
1   [25-65]     66.67   33.33
2   >65         50.00   50.00
```

**My problem is**: how could I have done this directly, with the appropriate Python code, from the original dataframe? `*data*.describe()` doesn't seem useful to retrieve appropriate information. I don't know enough Python to know if there are more useful instructions to do so. Have you ever seen this problem? How would you have solved it? Thanks for any advice.

**Below**, the code I used to build my small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["M",  "<25", "yes"],
             ["M",  "<25", "no"],  
             ["M",  "[25-65]", "no"],
             ["M",  "[25-65]", "yes"],
             ["M",  "[25-65]", "yes"],
             ["M",  ">65", "no"],
             ["M",  ">65", "yes"],
             ["F",  "<25", "yes"],
             ["F",  "<25", "yes"],  
             ["F",  "[25-65]", "yes"],
             ["F",  "[25-65]", "no"],
             ["F",  "[25-65]", "no"],
             ["F",  ">65", "yes"],
             ["F",  ">65", "no"]
         ],
         columns = [
             "sex",
             "age",
             "answer"
         ]
    )

df
```

Comment: Hi, @techytushar, this gives me a 50% proportion in all categories. , which is not the case. Don't we have to introduce `answer` somewhere?

Comment: Hey I misread the question this might be what you need `df[df['answer']=='yes'].groupby('age')['sex'].value_counts(normalize=True)`
But the percentages you have mentioned in the questions does not make sense, if F is 100% in first row then M should be 0?